# react native webview login before loaded webapp

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-native

I have an application which made by react native and other side I have a webapp that made by wordpress which has login page. I want to load the wordpress app as webview in react native but I have a question that how to can login in react native webview and go to the wordpress app

Comment: Can you add some more information?

Comment: I have 2 apps one react native and another wordpress, I want to load the wordpress app in react native as webview but I want to the user is logged in the wordpress app

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it you need to login on wordpress using a rect-native form.
To do this you need to you need to create an ajax request to login on wordpress, and then open the wordpress site.

Here you have more info about REST auth in wordpress:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Here you can see how to use ajax inside react-native:
https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-ajax-requests-react-native/

And here you have an example of all the manually process:
https://carlofontanos.com/user-login-with-wordpress-using-react-native/

Hope it helps!